# Pandas: Transpose data horizontal to vertical and have index value repeat with number of corresponding values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has an acct name, acct ID and then a number of products the account owns represented by the product name. The data needs to be transposed into a format so it can be uploaded to salesforce.

Input

```
  Account Name      Acct ID      crest       ptx      gtchange    gtfire    dfdata

0 csld solutions     1234                    ptx                  gtfire
1 global dynamics    0256        crest                gtchange              dfdata
2 running inc.       2564                             gtchange    gtfire
```

Output

```
  Account Name      Acct ID      Product 

0  csld solutions     1234         ptx
1  csld solutions     1234         gtfire
2  global dynamics    0256         crest                              
3  global dynamics    0256         gtchange
4  global dynamics    0256         dfdata
5  running inc.       2564         gtchange
6  running inc.       2564         gtfire
```

Comment: What have you already tried? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Look at `pd.DataFrame.melt`

Comment: I haven't solve the problem yet but I'm now reading the documentation on pd.DataFrame.melt and trying to use this function to transpose the data.